# How to inherit some attributes in directives

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating several directives (exorcises, fill-in-the-gaps, translations).

```
<exercises mode='register' data="rows">
  <fill-in-the-gaps></fill-in-the-gaps>
  <translations></translations>
</exercises>
```

i need to know how to inherit some attributes (mode, data) in directives child (fill-in-the-gaps, translations)?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use a controller in the `exercises` directive and hang those attributes there, then bring in the controller via `require`:

```
  app.module('foo').directive('exercises', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: function($scope, $attrs) {
        self = this
        $attrs.$observe('mode', function(value){ // use $scope.$watch here if you 
                                                 // want actual scope values
          self.mode = value
        })
      }
    }
  })

  app.module('foo').directive('fillInTheGaps', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '^excercises', // require a parent directive
      link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, excercisesCtrl) {
        console.log(excercisesCtrl.mode)  
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: this example is good because console.log(excercisesCtrl.mode) return the rigth value (registration) but ng-show return false. 
template is fillInTheGaps
<table class="table table-hover" ng-show="mode == 'registration'">